# FIRESTORE - Insert a subCollection inside a document

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection named Reports in my Firestore database, I've already done adding documents inside it. But my problem now is I want to add a Document with a SubCollection inside Reports, any Idea?

```
public CollectionReference Ref = firestore.collection("Reports");
Reports reports = new Reports(date, cash, total, discount, quantity, sum, employee);
Ref.add(reports);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Reports` cannot be a document, it can only be a **collection**. So assuming you have a database structure that look like this:

```
Firestore-root
    |
    --- Reports (collection)
          |
          --- reportId (document)
                |
                --- // report details
```

To add a new collection under the `reportId` document which in term contains other documents, please use the following line of code:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference ref = rootRef
    .collection("Reports").document(reportId)
    .collection("NewCollection").document(newCollectionId);
ref.add(reports);
```

And your new sturcture will look like this:

```
Firestore-root
    |
    --- Reports (collection)
          |
          --- reportId (document)
                |
                --- // report details
                |
                --- NewCollection (collection)
                       |
                       --- newCollectionId (document)
                              |
                              ---//  newCollectionId details
```

Comment: assuming that the Collection name is defined (Reports), what if I don't know the ID of the Document? or the document doesn't exist. how can I insert a document with a subCollection and some fields inside the Reports?

Comment: Why nt to know to id? You can know store it in a variable once you add the data to the database like this: `String id = yourRef.document().getId();` So having this `id` you can use in your reference whenever needed, right?

Comment: You can also have a subcollection under a document that doesn't exist.  There is no obligation to have an actual document in order to have subcollections under its document ID

Comment: If document id doesn't already exist, that's not a problem at all. In fact, after adding documents to a subcollection, the id will appear in the Firebase console *in italics*, indicating that it doesn't exist. There is still an opportunity to create the document, if you wish, but there is no obligation to do so. You can reach into the contents of the subcollection whether or not the document exists.  If you create the document, you can also delete it, and all of its subcollections will still exist.